# How can I show an array from a fetch() on a <FlatList>?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

Keep in mind I'm new to react-native and all, so expect some silly code.

I'm having a hard time trying to show them in a simple View, but  it's not working.

Even with componentDidMount() it shows an error of 'null is not an object' (evaluating 'this.state.groups.map')

If you guys have any advices, tutorials or guides, please feel free to share.

```
    export default class Request extends Component {

      state = {
        id: null,
        cod: '',
        description: '',
        groups: null,
      }

       componentDidMount(){
         this.pullRequest()
       }

      pullRequest = async() => {

        try{
          const response = await fetch(url)

          const results = await response.json()

          this.setState({groups: results.group})

          console.log(results)

          console.log(this.state.groups[0])
        }catch(err){
          console.error(err)
        }
      }

      postRequest = async() => {

        const model = { 'id'         : this.state.id,
                        'cod'        : this.state.cod,
                        'description': this.state.description,
                        'entity'     : this.state.id, //yeet
                      }
        try{
          const response = 
          await fetch(url,{
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(model),
      })

          const result = await response.json()

          this.setState({groups : result.group})

          console.log(this.state.groups)

          console.log('postresult: ')
          console.log(result)
        }catch(err){
          console.error(err)
        }
      }

      handleRequestId = id => {
        this.setState({id})
      }
      handleRequestCod = cod => {
        this.setState({cod})
      }
      handleRequestDescription = description => {
        this.setState({description})
      }

      requestPress = id => {
        // this.setState({tSample: this.state.id})
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={styles.loginContainer}>
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss} >
              <View style={[styles.logoContainer]}>
                <Image
                  style={styles.logo}
                  source={require('../assets/Icons/logo.png')}
                />
                //<Text style={styles.title}>NODE</Text>
                <View style={styles.voidView} > // I'm trying to show it here.
                  {this.state.groups.map(group => (
                    <Text>{group.cod}</Text>
                  ))}
                </View>
              </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            <View style={styles.formContainer}>
              <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="ID"
                placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.7)"
                value={this.state.id}
                onChangeText={this.handleRequestId}
                returnKeyType="go"
                // onSubmitEditing={this.setState.status}
                keyboardType="default"
                autoCapitalize="none"
                autoCorrect={false}
              />          
              <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="Cod"
                placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.7)"
                value={this.state.codigo}
                onChangeText={this.handleRequestCod}
                returnKeyType="go"
                // onSubmitEditing={this.setState.status}
                keyboardType="default"
                autoCapitalize="none"
                autoCorrect={false}
              />
              <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder="Description"
                placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.7)"
                value={this.state.descricao}
                onChangeText={this.handleRequestDescription}
                returnKeyType="go"
                // onSubmitEditing={this.setState.status}
                keyboardType="default"
                autoCapitalize="none"
                autoCorrect={false}
              />
              <Button 
                style={styles.buttonContainer}
                onPress={this.pullRequest} 
                title="REQUEST"
                // color="#0sd0a2"
              />
              <View>
                <Text>\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/</Text>
              </View>
              <Button 
                style={styles.buttonContainer}
                onPress={this.postRequest} 
                title="POST"
                // color="#0sd0a2"
              />
            </View>
          </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: You need to define your initialState as `groups: []`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
define initial state

constructor(props){
  super(props);
  state = {
    groups: []
  }
}

componentWillMount() { 
  **//once you fetch the data and updated the state like**
  this.setState({groups: results.group}) **// response**
}

in render

renderItem = ({item}) => {
  //how you need to view
}

render(){
  return(
    <FlatList
      data={this.state.grops} // you need to send array of objects
      renderItem={({item}) => this.renderItem}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it!

Answer (score 2):

When you have `groups` as an array in the state as `state = { groups: [] }` you initialize it as an array. `this.setState({groups: results.group})` would override that array with the values you get. its does not add it to `groups: []` .

You could initialize groups with the array objects you get and  `map` it. I'm not sure of the format of what you get but it could be like `state = { groups: {map: [] }}` or something depending on what you get.
or 
you can do `.concat()` if you want to push values onto the empty array you initialized.

Comment: Thank you for helping, wouldn't it be .push() instead of .concat()?

Comment: `.push()` would return a number when you try to assign it to a variable. Try `console.log(typeof groups);` after you setState with `.push()` .  [For more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Answer (score 1):

The reason it fails is that you define `groups` to be null, so the first time it renders, it tries to call "map" on null. You should initialize it with an empty array rather than with `null`, so that the map function is defined. In your component, the fetch call is async, so there will be no data to show at first until the call finishes. Having an empty array covers that case.

Comment: Thanks, that was it.